# Laravel OrderBy relationship count, but where an attribut in the relationship is something specific

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table called jokes and a table called votes. jokes has many votes. On my vote table I have an attribut called vote. vote can be either 1 or 0. 1 for up vote and 0 for down vote. In my system I want to let the user filter to se the most voted jokes. My question is how can I order my jokes with most up votes.

For a single joke I get the its up votes count like this:

```
 $vote_up_count = $joke->votes()->where('vote', '=', 1)->count();
```

But I have no clue how to OrderBy relationship count where vote in votes = 1.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long way to do it but it should work:

Step 1: Get a collection of jokes `$jokes`.

Step 2: Iterate over the jokes collection to get the income relationship model `$jokes->each(function ($joke){});`.

Step 3: For each votes relationship get the amount of votes equal to 1 by filtering only the votes that have `vote == 1`.
`$joke->votes->filter(function ($vote) {return ($vote->vote == 1);})->count()`.

Step 4: Add a count of votes property to the jokes model `$joke->count = $count`.

Step 5: Order the entire jokes collection in descending order on the new count property `sortByDesc('count')`.

Final result looks something like this:

```
$sortedByVoteCount = ($jokes->each(function ($joke) {
        $count = ($joke->votes->filter(function ($vote) {
            return ($vote->vote == 1);
        })->count());

        $joke->count = $count;

    })->sortByDesc('count'));
```